# Quel est le mot en français pour "proficient" (niveau de compétence linguistique)?

Tags: vocabulaire

En anglais, nous disons "proficient". Par exemple, dans un CV nous pouvons trouver: 
"French (proficient), Spanish (advanced)". Le niveau "proficient" est supérieur au niveau "advanced" et signifie que la personne parle couramment français.

Quel mot (adjectif) utiliser en français pour "proficient" dans ce sens-là?

Comment: En Europe on est maintenant censé donner son niveau de langue selon [l'échelle de référence du CECRL](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadre_europ%C3%A9en_commun_de_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_pour_les_langues#.C3.89chelle_globale). C2 - Niveau Maîtrise est ce qui correspond à  [C2-Mastery or proficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels).

Comment: @Laure Si tu rédige une réponse avec ce contenu, je supprimerai la mienne.

Comment: @MakorDal Sympa et honnête  mais j'ai suffisamment de réputation comme ça et FL a vraiment besoin de s'enrichir de nouveaux contributeurs.

Comment: Sauf à utiliser une echelle de référence, indiquer son niveau de langue dans un CV français pose systématiquement problème en raison de l'imprécision des termes généralement utilisés. Les qualificatifs usuels sont "scolaire" (non ambigu), "parlé,lu, écrit" (qui ne veut rien dire), "intermèdiaire" (mieux que scolaire, et moins bien que courant), "courant" (qui correspondrait a *advanced*, mais c'est peu précis), "bilingue" (parfois improprement utisé comme équivalent de *proficient*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour paraphraser Laure, il vaut mieux utiliser la [grille de référence CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels)

Par exemple, j'écrirais :

> Anglais (C1) Allemand (A2-B1)

Tous les niveaux C sont considéré comme "Proficient". Techniquement, de nombreux "natifs" ne l'atteignent pas (a cause des deux dernières clauses du C1 qui impliquent une certaine flexibilité, notament académique et une capacité d'expression complexe, maitrisant les niveaux de langages) et, pour un CV, un niveau B1-B2 est considéré comme suffisant, selon le poste bien sûr.

Answer (score 1):

In CVs, you would often use **courant** (meaning "fluent") to describe the level of proficiency you've mentioned here.

See: [here](http://www.gezim.fr/2015/03/presenter-niveaux-langue-cv/) (website on presenting your language skills in a CV)

Apart from courant, there is also *maîtrise*.

> **maîtrise**
>
> Fait de dominer techniquement, intellectuellement, scientifiquement : *Avoir la maîtrise d'une langue.*

Source: [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ma%C3%AEtrise/48746)

The verb maîtriser is also used quite often. (*Elle maîtrise bien le français.*)

Comment: Merci. Mais quel est alors l'adjectif pour indiquer le niveau? Par example, comme traduire "French (proficient), Spanish (advanced)"?  Cela serait  "français (????) espagnol (intermédiaire)".

Comment: @Ramiro J'ai modifié ma réponse, je pense "courant" convient bien dans ce contexte.

Comment: In Europe we are now expected to give language levels in accordance to the CEFR that gives the scales of foreign language proficiency. OP's question is confusing. "Niveau maîtrise" is what would be used and your answer was better before edition, except "maîtrise" alone is not sufficient.

Comment: @Laure "Niveau maîtrise" seems odd to me. I would mis-understand because of the university level "maîtrise" (Bac+4). On a CV, if not CEFR, I would expect "scolaire/débutant/notions", "moyen", "bon/avancé", "courant", "maternel"

Comment: @Random: Might seem odd to you but is the official wording in the [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) which purpose was to make it easier for educational institutions and employers to "evaluate the language qualifications of candidates to education admission or employment"  by establishing a "scientific" scale that would allow comparisons between the different existing tests in various countries. "scolaire/débutant/notions", "moyen", "bon/avancé", "courant", "maternel" mean nothing to an employer or to enter a university.

Comment: @Laure Saying A1, B2, or C1 is great indeed, but "Niveau maîtrise" seems confusing to me. On the list I gave, I said "if not CEFR" to make the difference. If you don't use the CEFR scale, I think those are the most common used terms to describe your skill

Comment: @Random Can't be confusing since "C2 - *Niveau Maîtrise*" is the actual wording in the [CEFR](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadre_europ%C3%A9en_commun_de_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_pour_les_langues#.C3.89chelle_globale). "Maitrise" is polysemic, you can explain "une maitrise universitaire" by going back to the original meaning of the word "maitrise": (avoir la qualité de maitre).

Comment: @Laure "C2 - Niveau Maîtrise" is not confusing then, "C2" makes it clear it refers to CEFR.